# Update Error When Updating Table Column with Date Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, window-functions, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to update my table column(TimeToPreviousOrder) with date differences between order dates by customer_id.

Initial Table

| customer_id | order_date | Order No | STANDVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2019-05-11 00:00:00.000 | 1833322 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2019-05-11 00:00:00.000 | 1833322 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2019-05-29 00:00:00.000 | 1833322 | 2 |
| 4321 | 2019-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 1844415 | 1 |
| 4321 | 2019-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 1844415 | 1 |
| 4321 | 2019-06-30 00:00:00.000 | 1844415 | 2 |
| 8765 | 2019-03-16 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 1 |
| 8765 | 2019-06-16 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 1 |
| 8765 | 2019-06-16 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 1 |
| 8765 | 2019-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 2 |

Expected Result

| customer_id | order_date | Order No | TimeToPreviousOrder | STANDVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2019-05-11 00:00:00.000 | 1833322 | 0 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2019-05-11 00:00:00.000 | 1833322 | 0 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2019-05-29 00:00:00.000 | 1833322 | 18 | 2 |
| 4321 | 2019-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 1844415 | 0 | 1 |
| 4321 | 2019-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 1844415 | 0 | 1 |
| 4321 | 2019-06-30 00:00:00.000 | 1844415 | 1 | 2 |
| 8765 | 2019-03-16 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 0 | 1 |
| 8765 | 2019-06-16 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 0 | 1 |
| 8765 | 2019-06-16 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 0 | 1 |
| 8765 | 2019-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 1866615 | 111 | 2 |

For example, Customer 1234 will have:

STANDVALUE= 1 , TimeToPreviousOrder = 0

STANDVALUE= 2, TimeToPreviousOrder = 18 Days

```
update #tmp set TimeToPreviousOrder=(select  DATEDIFF(day, COALESCE(v.order_date, u.order_date), u.order_date) new_TimeToPreviousOrder from 
        #tmp u OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP(1) v.order_date FROM #tmp v WHERE v.customer_id = u.customer_id AND v.order_date < u.order_date ORDER BY v.order_date DESC) v
        ORDER BY  u.customer_id,u.order_date )
```

Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28a7b)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh According to the shared fiddle, Its SQL SERVER

Comment: RESOLVED - SELECT *,
                       datediff(day,
                                lag([order_date]) OVER
                                    (
                                    PARTITION BY [customer_id]
                                    ORDER BY [order_date] asc, [order_no]
                                    ),
                                [order_date]
                           ) TimeToPreviousOrder ---as date diff
                FROM #tmp a where [customer_id] ='1234'

Comment: I tried the code below and it works -  SELECT *,
                       datediff(day,
                                lag([order_date]) OVER
                                    (
                                    PARTITION BY [customer_id]
                                    ORDER BY [order_date] asc, [order_no]
                                    ),
                                [order_date]
                           ) TimeToPreviousOrder ---as date diff
                FROM #tmp a where [customer_id] ='1234'

Answer (score 1):

If you are grouping data by customer_id and order_id then use :

```
select customer_id, order_date, order_no, 
  DATEDIFF(day, LAG(order_date, 1, order_date) over (partition by customer_id,order_no order by order_date), order_date)
from items;
```

If you are grouping data by customer_id only then :

```
select customer_id, order_date, order_no, 
  DATEDIFF(day, LAG(order_date, 1, order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date), order_date)
from items;
```

The `LAG` window function is a SQL function that allows you to access a previous row's value within the current result set.

```
LAG ( expression [, offset [, default ] ] ) OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

In our case offset will be `1` and the `default` when there is no previous record will be `order_date`

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kz597Vqw)

Comment: **@SelVazi** the CTE works but had the issue below

Comment: **@SelVazi** try with this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7e7a2/1 There is an error with Customer_id 4321 2019-06-11T00:00:00Z 1846773 2019-06-11T00:00:00Z **0.** **It should be 57**

Comment: WITH cte as (
  select *, LAG(order_date, 1, order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) as prev_date
  from items
)
select *, DATEDIFF(day, prev_date, order_date) as TimeToPreviousOrder
from cte;

Comment: I thought the partition must be by `customer_id` and `order_id`, so to get 57 then the partition must be by customer_id only. I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, datediff(day, lag([order_date]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [customer_id] ORDER BY [order_date] asc, [order_no] ), [order_date] ) TimeToPreviousOrder -FROM #tmp a where [customer_id] ='1234'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).